# Mistune Inline Lexar re.compile assistance

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm using mistune to parse some text, hyperlinking document numbers to the document management system on an internal site. Using the wiki_link example at https://github.com/lepture/mistune I'm finding anything surrounded with double square brackets and creating a iwl anchor (interwoven link protocal from HP/iManage/Autonomy). This works well enough, however, I was trying to identify the number with a doc# prefix (with or without some spaces between the # and the number). So if the text said `looking at doc# 25487657 as a sample...` the re.compile arguments would identify that number (can range from low 1000s to billions) based on the preceding 'doc#'. I can deal with splitting on the # in the output_interwoven_link method but have struggled with the regex.

Having always relied on search engines to get me to an example of a regex expression to solve my regex issues, I'm left ill equipped to craft the expression myself. How I do it now with the double square brackets looks like:

```
from mistune import Renderer, InlineGrammar, InlineLexer, Markdown
import re
import copy


class InterwovenLinkRenderer(Renderer):
    def interwoven_link(self, docnum):
        return '<a href="iwl:dms=dmssrv11&lib=Active&num=%s&ver=1&latest=1&command=opencmd">%s</a>' % (docnum, docnum)


class InterwovenLinkInlineLexer(InlineLexer):
    def enable_interwoven_link(self):
        self.rules.interwoven_link = re.compile(
            r'\[\['                   # [[
            r'([\d]+?)'               # Document Number
            r'\]\](?!\])'             # ]]
            #r'''(doc#[\d]+?)'''
        )

        self.default_rules = copy.copy(InlineLexer.default_rules)
        self.default_rules.insert(3, 'interwoven_link')

    def output_interwoven_link(self, m):
        text = m.group(1)
        #doc, docnum = text.split('#')
        return self.renderer.interwoven_link(text)


@register.filter(name='parse')
def parse(value=None):
    if value:
        renderer = InterwovenLinkRenderer()
        inline = InterwovenLinkInlineLexer(renderer)
        # enable the feature
        inline.enable_interwoven_link()
        markdown = Markdown(renderer, inline=inline)
        return markdown(value)
    else:
        return False
```

Any pointers for what I can use?

Comment: I may have it. `doc# *([\d]+)`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match any number following the string "doc#", the regex is `doc# (\d+)`

Comment: Yes, it seems the regex as you provided, and what I was trying earlier works outside of where I need it to. Works great at http://pythex.org/ and in my console but not when I put it in the `r'doc# *([\d]+)'` here; I suspect I'm not injecting it early enough or something else is grabbing the # before I am getting to it in mistune.

Comment: get rid of the `*` and see if it works (also you don't need the square brackets)

Comment: I should have said I tried your suggestion verbatim without success. I'm convinced it is something outside of the regex. I figure with popularity of hashtags mistune might have a built in thing pre-empting me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: eventually aiming for something like `(?:doc#? *|document *)(\d+)` but was trying to get back to a simpler form.